# Why list interface is returned instead of ArrayList interface implementation after explicit implementation

Tags: java, list, generics, interface, return

I know what is going on inside of my code, and how to fix an error. However, I do not understand *why* things happen the way they do. Specifically, why my method returns **interface List** instead of **ArrayList** interface implementation?

What confuses me the most is after implementing `moons` as `ArrayList`, it still returns the interface.

Thanks in advance!

```
    private static ArrayList<HeavenlyBody> makingSetOfMoons(){
        List<HeavenlyBody> moons = new ArrayList<>();
        for(HeavenlyBody planet : Main.planets){
            moons.addAll(planet.getSatellites());
        }
        return moons;
    }
```

Error output:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.List<com.practice.HeavenlyBody>', required: 'java.util.ArrayList<com.practice.HeavenlyBody>'
```

Comment: Java knows that moons is declared as a `List` not as an `ArrayList`. Change the method to return a `List` -- solved

Comment: Yeah, I know it is simple to change the return type or cast it. But why Java knows that is List and not ArrayList?? I made it the array list in the line  ```List<HeavenlyBody> moons = new ArrayList<>();```

Comment: You can change the variable that moons refers to at any time to another List subtype, and Java cannot tell if you might do this before returning the value. You must return the value *declared the variable*. The must match

Comment: This all gets down to the difference between a reference variable and a reference (or object), specifically the type of each. It is a fine distinction but an important one.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels I think, I start getting it now. "You must return the value declared the variable" meaning, if I declare interface variable, and attempt to return it, I will always return the list interface, even though I assigned/implemented it to the specific class, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your method declaration:

```
private static ArrayList<HeavenlyBody> makingSetOfMoons(){
```

Java expects the method to return an `ArrayList<HeavenlyBody>`

But you return the moons variable which is declared:

```
List<HeavenlyBody> moons = ....
```

It doesn't matter what type of List subtype that you assign to the variable -- Java sees the variable as a `List<HeavenlyBody>`, pure and simple. Even if you assign an `ArrayList<HeavenlyBody>` to this variable, the Java compiler cannot use this to do an automatic implicit cast for you, because you could later in the method change the object that the variable refers to, now or later, and this could cause problems. As Jon Skeet states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000730/522444):

> The compiler uses the declared type of the variable to know how it can be used... it's as simple as that.

One solution is to change the moons variable to:

```
ArrayList<HeavenlyBody> moons = ...
```

This would work but would be wrong since it is almost always better to "code to the interface" (see: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)). Better to change the return type expected by the method in its declaration:

```
private static List<HeavenlyBody> makingSetOfMoons() {
```

This all gets down to the difference between a reference variable and a reference (or object), specifically the type of each. It is a fine distinction but an important one.

The variable and its type:

```
List<HeavenlyBody> moons
```

This variable is a *reference* variable that refers to an object, as opposed to a *primitive* variable that refers to a primitive type.

Currently you assign this reference to the variable:

```
new ArrayList<>();
```

and so the type of the variable is `List<HeavenlyBody>` and the type of the reference that it refers to is `ArrayList<HeavenlyBody>`

Comment: Thank you, now it is more or less clear. Could you please elaborate what you mean by "This all gets down to the difference between a reference variable and a reference (or object), specifically the type of each. It is a fine distinction but an important one." or refer to the article?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler expects method to return object of type `ArrayList` or more specific one (class that extends `ArrayList`). However, the type of `moons` variable returned from the method is less specific, i.e. `List`.
In this case, it is not important for the compiler what specific type does an instance assigned to `moons` variable have - the implementation you are asking about - only the variable type matters.

I hope this answers your question, if not please ask, I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Important thing that you seem to be missing in your understanding is two parts of the following expression:

```java
Type identifier = new SubType();
```

Beware, that `identifier` is a variable *of type* `Type` (and **not directly** of type `SubType`), and it can store a reference to the object of any other type, as long as that "other" type is a subtype of `Type` (including `Type` itself, as type is a sub-type of itself in Java).

Therefore:

```java
private static ArrayList<HeavenlyBody> makingSetOfMoons() {
    List<HeavenlyBody> moons = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    return moons;
}
```

will not compile, as the type of `moons` is `List<HeavenlyBody>`.

---

Q: Why this is designed so?

A: [Because](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html)

> in Java programming language, every variable and every expression has a type that is known at compile time.<sub>JSL - Chapter 4: Types, Values, and Variables</sub>

Imagine you had:

```java
public ArrayList<SomeType> something(List<SomeType> list) {
    ...
    return list;
}
```

You can observe, that `List<SomeType> list` can accept *anything* that is sub-type of it; however, if you, in this case, were allowed to return `list` (of type `List<SomeType>`), there is a big chance you would have received a runtime exception, as not every sub-type of `List<E>` can be converted to `ArrayList<E>`.